# Problem with matching data outside html tags

Tags: regex

I am trying to come up with a way to match content that does **not** exist inside any xml or html tags.  I've read that using regular expressions is fundamentally bad for parsing xml/html, and I'm open for any solution that will solve my problem, but if a regex works too all the better.

Here's an example of what I'm looking for:

```
the lazy fox jumped <span>over</span> the brown fence.
```

What I want back is

```
the lazy fox jumped  the brown fence
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to clarify, the text you are parsing is not inside of a root xml tag? You just want to parse out any text that is inside of an xml tag, correct? So you are not really parsing xml, you are parsing text.

Comment: @bodnarbm That's correct, it's not in an xml document, it's actually text that's getting injected as html, but there's no root tag or anything

Comment: The problem with regex and HTML is malformed HTML.  Do you control the HTML and can you guarantee no malformed HTML, or is this "HTML in the wild"?

Comment: @cfeduke I have control over how the html is getting generated, and I'm pretty sure it's well formed, although I would have to check.  On a side note, I *believe* the only tag I'm concerned about is <span>.

Comment: It would help if knew which regex flavor you're using.

Comment: @Alan there are multiple flavors?  I'm using .NET if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a naive technique, but my first instinct would be to run the regular expression, figure out what text it matches within your parent string, and REMOVE it from that string, returning the remainder.  In pseudocode,

```
String input = "whatever";
matches = Regex.Matches(input,"<.*>.*?</.*>");
foreach (match m in Matches)
{
input = input.Remove(m.Value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, I'll try that.  Question, how would that handle two spans in sequence?  like this "the <span>lazy</span> fox <span>jumped</span> again"  In my case I would need that to return "the  fox  again"

Comment: That's where the star-question mark comes in. Defined in the .net regular expression syntax, it's a "lazy" (that is, non-greedy) match -- it'll slurp as few characters as possible while still matching the pattern. While <.*>.*<.*> would return "the again", the given pseudocode will match against the first closing span tag (the first possible match against the pattern); "the fox again" would be returned from that case.

Comment: @Jim Dagg: You should make the dot-stars inside the tags reluctant, too, e.g.: `"<.*?>"`. Also, you could do the job in one pass with `Regex.Replace(target, regex, "")`.

Comment: @Jim Oh awesome! I didn't know you could do that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Run this one over the string:

```
s/\(.*\)<.*>.*<.*>\(.*\)/\1\2/
```

You might need to change some of the details based on implementation (escaping parentheses may not be required, for example), but that'll get exactly what you want (with the double space and everything in the middle).

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  I'll give it a try!